# Should I rebalance winter tires after several years in storage?

Tags: tires, winter, wheel-balance

Winter wheels/tires spent 8 years in storage due to... lack of snow. They were balanced when originally purchased, and have maybe 15K miles on them after two seasons.

I'm planning to use them this winter... Should I rebalance before mounting on my car? Does wheel balance change over time, even when not used?

Looking for advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you should not need to rebalance them, however ...

You have a bigger problem than balancing. More than likely, your tires are past their usable lifespan, even if they do have plenty of tread left. Tires only last so long whether they are used or not. [The British Rubber Manufacturers Association (BRMA)](https://www.tirerack.com/upgrade-garage/how-does-age-affect-tires-part-1) recommends:

> BRMA members strongly recommend that unused tyres should not be put into service if they are over six years old and that all tyres should be replaced ten years from the date of their manufacture.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that; Will need a new set of tires, which will solve the balancing problem too :)